# Find rows that are different by ID for specific columns

Tags: r

Suppose that we have the following data frame:

```
ID <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5)
age <- c(25, 25, 25, 22, 22, 56, 56, 56, 80, 33, 33, 90, 90, 90)
gender <- c("m", "m", "m", "f", "f", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "f", "f", "m")
company <- c("c1", "c2", "c2", "c3", "c3", "c1", "c1", "c1", "c1", "c5", "c5", "c3", "c4", "c5")
income <- c(1000, 1000, 1000, 500, 1700, 200, 200, 250, 500, 700, 700, 300, 350, 300)

df <- data.frame(ID, age, gender, company, income)
```

I need to find the row that have different values by ID for age, gender, and income. I don't care about the company whether they are same or different.

So after processing, here is the output:

[image]

BONUS,

Can we create another data frame include the list of variables that are different by id. For example:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option would be to group by 'ID', check whether the number of distinct elements in 'age', 'gender', 'income' is equal to 1 and then negate (`!`)

```
library(dplyr)
out <- df %>%  
         group_by(ID) %>%
         filter(!(n_distinct(age) == 1 &
             n_distinct(gender) == 1 & 
             n_distinct(income) == 1))
out
# A tibble: 9 x 5
# Groups:   ID [3]
#     ID   age gender company income
#  <dbl> <dbl> <fct>  <fct>    <dbl>
#1     2    22 f      c3         500
#2     2    22 f      c3        1700
#3     3    56 m      c1         200
#4     3    56 m      c1         200
#5     3    56 m      c1         250
#6     3    80 m      c1         500
#7     5    90 f      c3         300
#8     5    90 f      c4         350
#9     5    90 m      c5         300
```

If there are many variable, another option i `filter_at`

```
df %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    filter_at(vars(age, gender, income), any_vars(!(n_distinct(.) == 1)))
```

From the above, we can get the ssecond output with

```
library(tidyr)
out %>% 
    select(-company) %>%
    gather(key, val, - ID) %>% 
    group_by(key, add = TRUE) %>% 
    filter(n_distinct(val) > 1) %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    summarise(Different = toString(unique(key)))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#     ID Different  
#  <dbl> <chr>      
#1     2 income     
#2     3 age, income
#3     5 gender, income
```

Comment: how can i add age and gender to the n_distinct function?

Comment: @user9292 In your expected output, I don't see `age` differs for ID - 5

Comment: sorry, I just fixed it

Comment: @user9292. Please check your input and output.  The input is not matching.  The last element for 'gender' is `f` instead of `"M"`

Comment: Fixed. Thanks! also, would ```n_distinct(interaction(age, gender, income)``` do the same?

Comment: @user9292. It may not work because the combination matters

Comment: is there a way to speed up the code used to generate the results in the ```out```. My data is a bit large and it's taking long time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In base R, we can `split` `c("age", "gender", "income")` column based on `ID` find out `ID`'s which have more than 1 `unique` row and subset them.

```
df[df$ID %in% unique(df$ID)[sapply(split(df[c("age", "gender", "income")], df$ID), 
              function(x) nrow(unique(x)) > 1)], ]

#   ID age gender company income
#4   2  22      f      c3    500
#5   2  22      f      c3   1700
#6   3  56      m      c1    200
#7   3  56      m      c1    200
#8   3  56      m      c1    250
#9   3  80      m      c1    500
#12  5  90      f      c3    300
#13  5  90      f      c4    350
#14  5  90      m      c5    300
```